# Restrict attribute value in ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, fields-attributes

Is there a way in ArcObjects to restrict attribute value when user modifies it. Let's say for integer value between 0-10 or for string : no/yes?

Answer (score 3):

Stopping users from adding invalid values is really the task of a Geodatabase [domain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000001000000). Shapefiles do not support domains. I would strongly suggest you explore these options first as they can be set through ArcMap or ArcCatalog and do not require any programming with ArcObjects. It's also good Geodatabase design if you assign domains to fields.

But you do not say how you intend the user to enter these values? Is it through the standard interface (if so use domains!) or some custom interface? If it is a custom form then you have total control of what is captured before it is written to the FeatureClass. So it's not really an ArcObjects issue its more of a VB or C# form issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created Add-on toolbar and button that creates empty shapefiles for me. i also have C# form pop up through which i take default attribute values from user. So obviously I impose restriction while taking default values from C# form. However user can modify attribute table later and may use any other value which is not expected. Looks like domain is solution in that case!

Comment: You could perhaps disable editing once the user has input their values in the form to prevent them updating the attribute table incorrectly. But domains are definitely a better way to go.

Comment: how do i disable editing? if i do so, value in attribute field becomes NULL. do you have example to share?